# NODE.JS connect to multiple database on the fly gives me error

Tags: node.js, database, loopback

I am creating an API where I need to connect to different database using thier credentials on the fly. I need to make functionality similar to MySql workbench - test connection. Currently, I need to deal with MySql and MSSql server. I have to check all the permutation and combination for wrong credentials. i.e. if I pass correct credentials for example, correct host, username, password, port but wrong connector instead of MySql I pass Mssql. That is throwing an exception.

```
var db = {
   host           : data.hostName,
   port           : data.port,
   database       : data.database,
   username       : data.userName,
   password       : data.password,
   connector      : response[0].node_js_connector
 }

 var dataSource = new DataSource(db.connector, db);
 dataSource.on('connected', function (er) {  
   if(er) {
     console.log("reject");  
     reject(er);
   }
   else {
     console.log("resolve");
     resolve('Work With Database');
   }
 });
 dataSource.on('error', function (er) {
   if(er) {
     console.log("reject1");  
     reject(er);
   }
   else {
     console.log("reject1");
     reject('Not Connected Databse');
   }
 });
```

I have also put the code in try/catch block to handle exception. However, I am not able to catch it. Currently, I am getting following error:

```
throw new RangeError('Index out of range'); 

RangeError: Index out of range
    at checkOffset (buffer.js:968:11)
    at Buffer.readUInt8 (buffer.js:1006:5)
```

It would be a great help, if someone can assist me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the length of `response` is 0. How is it defined?

Comment: @spicypumpkin first of all i didn't get the `response`. The exposition will occurs before get the 'response'.

Comment: Well, all I can tell you is that you are trying to get the 1st element from an empty array `response`, hence the `IndexError`. You're gonna have to figure out a way to check whether the array is empty or not. Hope that helps.

Comment: @spicypumpkin I am able to get response. My connector value is either "mssql" or "mysql" depending on params I pass. I always get response. I have full db object. The only thing is intentionally for testing purpose I am passing wrong connector, and it is throwing error. I am producing same error as "https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/issues/309". What I want is some way to handle it

Comment: Ooh, got it, upon closer inspection I realized you're using both event emitters and promises. That's why `try`/`catch` won't work. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358054/catch-all-error-events-from-any-eventemitter-in-node) to handle emitted errors.

Comment: @spicypumpkin, thanks for your help. now it's work in properly.

Answer (score 0):

i use process.on() method to headland `uncaughtException`. this method handle all the exception in file execution time. so, in this time `uncaughtException` will handle my `Index out of range` exception. and reject my dataSource connection.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log('UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION - keeping process alive:', err); // err.message is "foobar"
    reject('Connected Faile');
});
```